# Vicidial PHP/Json/Mysql combination to pull data in monitor

Tags: php, mysql, json

The question title can be very vague but I didnt know what exactly to write so lets get to the point

I have a script that pull data from a Vicidial database to display it TV screen

Now it basically works well when there is only one Server involved cause it has only one Extension to handle, but the thing gets more complicated when there are two extensions. Better I show you the code :

```
$start_time = time();
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT
            extension,
            vicidial_live_agents.user,
            conf_exten,
            vicidial_live_agents.status,
            vicidial_live_agents.server_ip,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_call_time) as last_call_time,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_call_finish) as last_call_finish,
            call_server_ip,
            vicidial_live_agents.campaign_id,
            vicidial_users.user_group,
            vicidial_users.full_name,
            vicidial_live_agents.comments,
            vicidial_live_agents.calls_today,
            vicidial_live_agents.callerid,
            lead_id,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_state_change) as last_state_change,
            on_hook_agent,
            ring_callerid,
            agent_log_id
        FROM
            vicidial_live_agents,
            vicidial_users
        WHERE
            vicidial_live_agents.user = vicidial_users.user";

$db = new mysqli("192.168.X.X", "cron", "XXXXXX", "asterisk");


$result = $db->query($sql);

$sql2 = "select callerid,lead_id,phone_number from vicidial_auto_calls";
$cidresult = $db->query($sql2);
$callerids = '';
while ($row = $cidresult->fetch_assoc()){
    $callerids .= $row['callerid'] . "|";
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $status = $row['status'];

    if ($row['on_hook_agent'] == 'Y')
        $status = 'RING';

    // 3-way Check
    if ($row['lead_id'] != 0){
        $sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_call_time) FROM vicidial_live_agents WHERE lead_id = '" . $db->escape_string($row['lead_id']) . "' AND status = 'INCALL' ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_call_time) DESC";
        $r2 = $db->query($sql);
        if (!$r2){
            printf("Error: %s\n", $db->error);
        } else {
            if ($r2->num_rows > 1){
                $status = "3-WAY";
            }
        }
    }

    $epoch_sec = 0;
    if (preg_match("/READY|PAUSED/i", $row['status'])){
        $epoch_sec = $row['last_state_change'];

        if ($row['lead_id'] > 0){
            $status = 'DISPO';
        }
    } else {
        $epoch_sec = $row['last_call_time'];
    }

    if (preg_match("/INCALL/i", $status)){
        $sql4 = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(parked_time) AS pt FROM parked_channels WHERE channel_group = '" . $db->escape_string($row['callerid']) . "'";
        $q4 = $db->query($sql4);

        if ($q4->num_rows > 0){
            $status = 'PARK';
            $rowP = $q4->fetch_assoc();
            $epoch_sec = $rowP['pt'];
        } else{
            if (!preg_match("/" . $row['callerid'] . "\|/",$callerids)){
                $epoch_sec = $row['last_state_change'];

                $status = 'DEAD';
            }
        }
    }

    switch($status){
        case 'DISPO':
            $colour = '8e44ad';
            break;
        case 'QUEUE':
            $colour = '9b59b6';
            break;
        case 'INCALL':
            $colour = '3498db';
            break;
        case 'PARK':
            $colour = 'e67e22';
            break;
        case 'DEAD':
            $colour = '004D86';
            $status = 'GONE';
            break;
        case '3-WAY':
            $colour = '1abc9c';
            break;
        case 'RING':
            $colour = '16a085';
            break;
        case 'PAUSED':
            $colour = 'c0392b';
            break;
        case 'CLOSER':
            $status = 'READY (C)';
        case 'READY':
            $colour = '27ae60';
            break;
        default:
            $colour = 'D2BEAA';
            break;
    }

    $data[$row['extension']] = array(
        'user' => $row['user'],
        'status' => $status,
        'conf_exten' => $row['conf_exten'],
        'seconds' => ( time() - $epoch_sec ),
        'campaign_id' => $row['campaign_id'],
        'user_group' => $row['user_group'],
        'full_name' => $row['full_name'],
        'calls_today' => $row['calls_today'],
        'lead_id' => $row['lead_id'],
        'colour' => $colour
    );

}
```

Now for example when the Extension is SIP/P023 everything works all right, but since the users can use both extension SIP/**P**023 and SIP/**B**023 I need to find a wait that this you have the same output

[Screenshot of what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd1pj.png)

Now i need to make a single square with the result of either one of the extension witch is active (they cant ever be active in the same time)

I dont know if i have explained myself but i hope at least

Comment: So you need your code to decide which one is active and display that box?

Comment: Yes thats exately what i need

Comment: How are users using more than 1 extension? Do they have phone aliases setup or something?

Comment: Yes phones have aliases setup, in this case (A023) but dont know how to use them outside Vicidial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the API? here: http://www.vicidial.org/docs/NON-AGENT_API.txt

Look for the agent_status section. That will give you realtime stats of the user. So all you have to do is set your script to refresh that at whatever interval you want. Let me know if you need more help with the api.

Comment: Its a great place to start, thanks for the head-up , I will surely try and will ask again if i am stuck at something thank you @dkeeper09